# How to change interval time under a condition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I need a function that will print letters one by one but make pauses after ",".
I tried to do it like this but it didn't work :

```
var span = document.getElementById('text')
function print(string){
  var i = 0
  var time = 50
  var timer = setInterval(function(){
    span.innerHTML += string[i++]
    if(string[i] == ","){
      time = 150
    }else{
      time = 50
    }  
  },time)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure you can change the time of `setTimeinterval` once defined. It is better to use a `setTimeout`. I'm using recursive function to achieve the desired -

```
function print(string, i){
  var time = 50
  if(string[i]==",") time = 1000
  setTimeout(function(){
    span.innerHTML += string[i]
    if(i<string.length-1) print(string,++i)
  },time)

}
```

complete example can be found [here](https://jsbin.com/nitinaretu/edit?html,console,output)

Comment: This is is a great answer. You don't need to use an external site for posting JS/HTML/CSS snippets though, for future reference. There's a built in widget for this.

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't think `setInterval` is what you're looking for. Since it seems you just want to print each character with a delay, `setTimeout` would work best in this situation.

I would break this up so that you can focus on printing a single character at a time, and then you can call that in your main `print` function for each character in the string.

This is how I would do something like this, using Promises:

```
const printCharacter = (ch, idx) => new Promise(resolve => {
    let time = 50 * idx;

    if(ch === ',') {
        time = 150 + time * idx;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        const span = document.getElementById('text');
        span.innerHTML += ch;
        resolve();
    }, time)
});

const print = async string => {
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        await printCharacter(string[i], i);
    }
};
```

There are some bugs that could present itself here, such as the timing for multiple commas present in your base string. This is just my first iteration.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using an interval, I recommend using a for loop to iterate the string and a Promise to pause as long as desired.

Side note, use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. The former is like `myCar.cangeTires(); myCar.closeDoors()`, the latter is like `myCar.do('change tires'); myCar.do('close doors');`.

```js
let sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

var span = document.getElementById('text');
let print = async string => {
  span.textContent = '';
  for (let c of string) {
    span.textContent += c;
    await sleep(c === ',' ? 500 : 50);
  }
};

print('my text, and a comma');
```

```html
<span id="text"></span>
```

Comment: I wouldn't answer a question about vanilla JS with JS code that only runs in some browsers/Node.js. Using asynchrony seems incredible overkill for this...

Comment: Like why would you `await` `setInterval` when you can just use `setInterval`? What does a `Promise` do to help the solution? Just seems very convoluted. This would be perhaps be a good answer if the OP explicitly stated he wanted to use an asynchronous approach.

Comment: `Async`'s been supported since chrome 55. I wouldn't say  avoiding unnecessary callbacks is "overkill", I'd say it's expected of any (competent) developer.

Comment: Right, but IE still remains widely used in the wild because a lot of companies hopped on the SilverLight train at some point, or they have a Microsoft stack (and Microsoft was heavy on browser technologies until the security flaws came), and Promises are -not- supported in IE without a polyfill. It's definitely overkill, and if throw Promises at every problem no matter what the complexity is, it's going to make your code very hard to follow for no evident reason.

Comment: It would be kind of like using `localStorage` or `IndexedDB` to store plain arrays just because you can. It's not necessary or practical and will make your code hard to follow. (A large part of reading code is reasoning about why something is the way it is.. when you can't reason about it at a higher level, it becomes hard to understand whether or not what's happening at a lower level is correct or not)

Comment: Edge does not replace IE at all my friend. It was meant to be the successor to IE, but IE has a -lot- of Browser technologies exclusive to it that many companies rely on, like SSRS. Also using cross-browser JS isn't "outdated" or "bad practice", the best practice is to always use JS that will run in any environment or use polyfills. Hence, the answer is overly complicated.